# Single action dispatch results in multiple effect call until Maximum call stack size exceded

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx, ngrx-effects

```
@effect()
public loadAccommodations$: Observable = this.actions$
  .ofType(PAA.PROPERTY_LOAD_REQUEST)
      // .debounce(300) 
      // introducing this mitigates the flood but does not resolve the issue
  .switchMap((action: Action) => {
     return this.propertyAccommodationsService.loadAccommodations(action.payload.id)
      .takeUntil(this.loadAccommodations$)
      .map((response: IResponseSuccess) => PAA.loadSuccess(action.payload, response))
      .catch((error: Error) => {
         const errorNotification = errorNotificationFactory(error.message);
         this.notificationService(errorNotification)
         return of( PAA.loadFailure() );
    });
  });
```

After dispatch PAA.PROPERTY_LOAD_REQUEST only once my effect intercepts this action many times until Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Versions:
"angular/core": "2.4.6",

"@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",

"@ngrx/store": "^2.2.1",

"@ngrx/effects": "^2.0.1",

"rxjs": "5.0.2",

Note: effects are registered only once in app.module.

Answer (score 0):

An `@Effect` does dispatch an Action itself. Your Effect dispatches the same Action again and again until either the call-stack is exeeded or the call returns.

You need to add `dispatch: false` to the Effect decorator:

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
```

Or you dispatch another action:

```
.switchMap((action: Action) => {
    this.propertyService.load(action.payload);
    return Observable.of({ type: 'LOADING_DATA' });
});
```

Comment: Thank you David, I updated the problem. I did not dispatch the same action ( loadRequest ) but one of two different actions ( loadSuccess or loadFailure).

Comment: So does it work now or not? Or is there another problem? How do you dispatch your action?

Comment: No it does not works, as I said my effect returns one action completely unrelated with the trigger action.

Comment: Oh ok, so then there seems to be nothing wrong with your Effect. How and where do you dispatch the Action?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was caused by takeUntil in this piece of code:

```
 return this.propertyAccommodationsService
   .loadAccommodations(action.payload.id)
   .takeUntil(this.loadAccommodations$)
```

By dispatching 2 PROPERTY_LOAD_REQUEST actions, the second one triggered takeUntil() operator which resulted in multiple effects calls.
In my case takeUntil(effect) is unnecessary so I could delete it but still, I can't figure out why this operator results in running multiple times the effect.